# How can I get aerial view with the Google Maps Javascript API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to configure a google map object to show me a aerial view:

```
var map;
function initMap() {
    detectBrowser();

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: 34.05, lng: -118.25},
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
        zoom: 6,
        heading: 90,
        tilt: 45
    });

    //map.enableRotation()

    map.setTilt(45);
    GMap2.enableRotation();


    //GLargeMapControl3D

}

function detectBrowser() {
    var useragent = navigator.userAgent;
    var mapdiv = document.getElementById("map");

    if (useragent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1 || useragent.indexOf('Android') != -1 ) {
        mapdiv.style.width = '100%';
        mapdiv.style.height = '100%';
    } else {
        mapdiv.style.width = '1000px';
        mapdiv.style.height = '800px';
    }
```

}

I can get the 45 deg view. But not the aerial view. I do not see the camera tilt controls either.

Somehow this url seems to have it: https://www.google.com/maps/@25.7541032,-80.192274,407a,35y,78.6t/data=!3m1!1e3

From here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/rLDvD6qFsS4

Comment: `GMap2.enableRotation` is a Google Maps API v2 function, but the rest of your code looks like you're using Google Maps API v3.  The two API's aren't cross-compatible; you should probably delete that line and any else that's using API v2 code.  See https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/v2tov3

Comment: Thanks Duncan I did that. As for the aerial view, maybe there is no support for that in v3.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `tilt` value to 0.

```
var map;
function initMap() {
    detectBrowser();

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: 34.05, lng: -118.25},
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
        zoom: 18,
        heading: 90,
        tilt: 0
    });

    //map.enableRotation()

    //map.setTilt(45);
    GMap2.enableRotation();


    //GLargeMapControl3D

}

function detectBrowser() {
    var useragent = navigator.userAgent;
    var mapdiv = document.getElementById("map");

    if (useragent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1 || useragent.indexOf('Android') != -1 ) {
        mapdiv.style.width = '100%';
        mapdiv.style.height = '100%';
    } else {
        mapdiv.style.width = '1000px';
        mapdiv.style.height = '800px';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That doesn't seem to work however.

Comment: Go to [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/googleapi/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_map_controls_add) and paste the code from [this page](http://hastebin.com/alibuhopav.xml]). Change the `tilt` value and see what happens.

Comment: Yep, that's the 45 degree view. I do get that wherever 45 degree imagery is available. I was asking about tilting the camera even more as in this link: https://www.google.com/maps/@25.7541032,-80.192274,407a,35y,78.6t/data=!3m1!1e3